# Loading or Inserting data from another table to an existing table using MS Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, database-connection

I'm a beginner in MS Visual Studio and what I would like to achieve is to transfer data from a table to an existing table using MS visual Studio. Both tables are stored in the same Server. Everytime I do it in OLE DB Destination Editor and put the sql script in the sql command text and it gives me an error.

Here's what I did..

I was hoping to move some data from TEST_Schema.dbo.ResourceTable using this simple select statement inside the sql command text in OLE DB source editor

Select ProfileID, FullName, SupervisorID from TEST_Schema.dbo.ResourceTable

---

and I want to insert the data to BI_Schema.dbo.Destination_Current_Resource

---

I have put this insert query inside the sql command text in OLE DB Destination Editor

insert into BI_Schema.dbo.Destination_Current_Resource(ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID)

Then I end up with an error. I must have done something wrong that's why I need help.

Thank you and I will look forward to your immediate reply.

--Beau

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statements you posted look right -- what errors are you getting?  Are you running the entire query below:

```
INSERT INTO BI_Schema.dbo.Destination_Current_Resource(ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID)
SELECT ProfileID, FullName, SupervisorID 
FROM TEST_Schema.dbo.ResourceTable
```

Then your SQL Command would look like this:

```
string insertString = @"INSERT INTO BI_Schema.dbo.Destination_Current_Resource(ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID)
                        SELECT ProfileID, FullName, SupervisorID 
                        FROM TEST_Schema.dbo.ResourceTable";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertString, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```